# How to document an event emitter returned

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, eventemitter

How to document the events emitted by `stream` returned in `MyFunc()` with JSDoc?

```
/**
 * [MyFunc description]
 * @param  {Object} opts - [description]
 * @return {Stream} - [description]
 */
function MyFunc (opts) {
  // stream is an EventEmitter
  var stream = new MyEventEmitter();

  stream.emit('event1', ... );
  stream.emit('event2', ... );

  return stream;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can document these behaviors by documenting your events (`event1`, `event2`, ...) as `@event MyFunc#event1` and MyFunc, or whoever does the emitting, with `@fires MyFunc#event1`.

You can also document functions that listen to those events with `@listens MyFunc#event:event1`.

Here are the official JSDoc pages for the aforementioned tags:

- https://jsdoc.app/tags-event.html
- https://jsdoc.app/tags-fires.html
- https://jsdoc.app/tags-listens.html

Do note some nuance around "event" mentioned in the tags event page, repeating here:

> JSDoc automatically prepends the namespace `event:` to each event's name. In general, you must include this namespace when you link to the event in another doclet. (The `@fires` tag is a *notable exception*; it allows you to omit the namespace.)