# JSDoc Documenting EventEmitter events with ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, es6-class

How does one document events for a class that extends EventEmitter to work in VS Code? I can't find any working examples, and I can't find any SO other than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652398/how-to-document-an-event-emitter-returned) which has no example. The page that it links to (https://jsdoc.app/tags-event.html) also does not seem to be working, as I tried to replicate it:

```js
class Test extends EventEmitter {
  /**
   * @fires Test#name
   */
  run () {
    this.emit('name', 1)
  }
}

/**
 * Snowball Event
 * @event Test#name
 * @type {number}
 */

const t = new Test()
t.run()
t.on('')
```

VS Code doesn't seem to detect that `name` is a documented event when I try to write `t.on('`. (I've tried putting `@fires` above the run method as well)

Comment: You have the event documentation block in a completely different place from where the documentation you linked to has it. Does it work if you put it where the documentation shows putting it?

Comment: (You're also not sending a number with it.)

Comment: Nope. I put it there because I assumed it would make no difference since it appears to function the same way as  `@typedef`. But it does not work. Emitting a number does not actually change anything either.

Comment: as TJ has said, you haven't followed the example you posted a link to at all - try putting the `@event Test#name` etc just above `this.emit` and the `@fires Test#name` etc just above `run`

Comment: As I've said in my comment, it made no difference. I've just edited my original post to make that point. And no it does not work - I've tried putting it in all kinds of places and VS Code does not detect it.

Comment: Just wondering if anyone found a solution for this as I'm having the same problem.